# Alfresco 5.1 online edit

Tags: office, alfresco

Alfresco 5.1 + Microsoft Office 2013, проблема следующая при нажатии кнопки онлайн едит открывается программа word/exel, но документ сам в программу не поддгружается. Пробовал через реестр менять ключи авторизации - не помогает ! что еще мог просмотреть?

Answer (score 1):

Все делается по данной инструкции http://docs.alfresco.com/aos1.1/tasks/aos-config-nonSSL.html исключения может быть только если офис 2013 x64 там идет не DWORD, а QWORD и на этом сам ошибся